# Multi Tenant Job Scheduler

Tags: .net, cluster-computing, multi-tenant, job-scheduling

I would like to build a job schedule system which can schedule jobs on a cluster which is going to be shared among several isolated tenants.

Every tenant need to track their jobs on this shared cluster. Does such a thing already exist? I really want to know the features of such scheduling system. Stuff from throttling to security. Any lead is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in recent years and with the advent of virtualization technology, many scheduling algorithms have been proposed for multi-tenant distributed virtualized systems. See [this resource](http://www.springerlink.com/index/K172H5P30560V8H6.pdf) and its related works for more info.